# I was unable to fund another wallet since this morning

Tags: blockchain

[image]
Hello everyone, I have been trying to transfer some amount from my wallet to another bitcoin address but didn't successful since morning, please I need help on this critical issue.

Comment: That's funny. The problem is caused by transactions that haven't confirmed, but the transactions have plenty of fee.

Comment: How do I solve it? @Nick O'Dell and how are my going to know if it's confirmed?